# Convexity of spherical curves

Tags: differential-geometry, convex-analysis, curves, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

Let $\gamma$ be a smooth curve in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. We say that $\gamma$ is *convex* if it lies on the boundary of its convex hull. Recall that the *convex hull* of $\gamma$ is the set of all convex combinations of points of $\gamma$—or, equivalently, the minimal convex set containing $\gamma$.

I am a bit confused about this definition and its relation to the classical definition of convexity for planar curves.

In particular, I would like to ask the following question: if $\gamma$ is a spherical curve, i.e., it lies on $\mathbb{S}^{2} \subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$, is it true that $\gamma$ is automatically convex?

Comment: i wonder what "boundary" means

Comment: Maybe "can’t be written as a convex combo of points in the hull with all coefficients positive"?

Comment: @Timkinsella Yes, the curve is made of extreme points.

Comment: Which is the same as not lying in the interior of a line segment in the hull.  so a spherical curve is convex. Points on a sphere can’t lie in the interior of a line segment contained in the ball the sphere bounds (the ball contains the hull)